# Send Grid Email sending failed in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

When we try to send email from cloud service using send grid it is getting failed(Failure sending mail.   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)). Same packages are deployed in different portal and it is working fine. Can you please suggest

Comment: Hi @siva-prakash. Can you please include the stack trace and any additional logs you have related to the exception/failure?

Comment: Hey, Can you share code for sending mail?